# Search span by id regular expression in Node

Tags: html, search

I have this text, in a node, or in a text to be treated. And what I would like is to replace all the content within the span tag that contains the regular expression id = '393_.

```
<span id = "393_1"> <div> haheoiaoajo </div> </span>
<span id = "393_2"> <div> PRUEBA </div> </span>
<span id='1234'>Hello</span>
```

I've tried with these expressions but they do not work

```
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("span");
        Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate("//*[@id='393']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

I can only find the first, and not with the regular expression, but exactly the id, and what I need is to replace all the contents of all those containing that regular expression, thank you very much in advance